# make a list of lm objects, retain their class

Tags: r, plyr

Apologies for such a rudimentary question--I must be missing something obvious.

I want to build a list of `lm` objects, which I'm then going to use in an `llply` call to perform mediation analysis on this list. But this is immaterial--I just first want to make a list of length m (where m is the set of models) and each element within m will itself contain n `lm` objects.

So in this simple example

```
d1 <- data.frame(x1 = runif(100, 0, 1),
             x2 = runif(100, 0, 1),
             x3 = runif(100, 0, 1),
             y1 = runif(100, 0, 1),
             y2 = runif(100, 0, 1),
             y3 = runif(100, 0, 1))

m1 <- lm(y1 ~ x1 + x2 + x3, data = d1)
m2 <- lm(x1 ~ x2 + x3, data = d1)
m3 <- lm(y2 ~ x1 + x2 + x3, data = d1)
m4 <- lm(x2 ~ x1 + x3, data = d1)
m5 <- lm(y3 ~ y1 + y2 + x3, data = d1)
m6 <- lm(x3 ~ x1 + x2, data = d1)
```

I want a list containing 3 elements, and the first element will contain `m1` and `m2`, the second will contain `m3` and `m4`, etc. My initial attempt is sort of right, but the lmm objects don't retain their class.

```
mlist <- list(c(m1,m2),
              c(m3,m4),
              c(m5,m6))
```

It has the right length (ie `length(mlist)` equals 3), but I thought I could access the `lm` object itself with

```
class(mlist[1][[1]])
```

but this element is apparently a list.

Am I screwing up how I build the list in the first step, or is this something more fundamental regarding lm objects?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, you're just getting confused with `c` and list indexing. Try this:

```
mlist <- list(list(m1,m2),
              list(m3,m4),
              list(m5,m6))
> class(mlist[[1]][[1]])
[1] "lm"
```

So `c` will concatenate lists by flattening them. In the case of a `lm` object, that basically means it's flattening each `lm` object in a list of each of the object components, and then concatenating all those lists together. `c` is more intuitively used on atomic vectors.

The indexing of lists often trips people up. The thing to remember is that `[` will always return a sub-list, while `[[` selects an element.

In my example above, this means that `mlist[1]` will return a list of length one. That first element *is still a list*. So you'd have to do something like `mlist[1][[1]][[1]]` to get all the way down to the `lm` object that way.

Comment: brilliant, thanks. i still have a ton to learn about lists and indexing.

Comment: Is there a way to append all these retained-class objects to a list without flatting the objects? In other words, when I do mlist <- append(tmpdata, mlist) it flattens out the object class again.

Comment: @Err If `m` is a `lm()` object, then `my_list <- list(m,m); append(my_list,list(m))` seems to do what you want?