# I would like to apply msmFit function to each day of minutely time series. How could I build a list of 'lm' class object?

Tags: r, list, time-series, rstudio, lm

I have a 3 months time series with minutely data and I need to perform msmFit function for each day. The function comes from 'MSwM package'. My time series is an xts object.

I split data with 'split' function in this way:

`US.data.daily<-split(US.data2,"days")`

The results is a 'list' object with 91 one elements.
'msmFit' requires 'lm' object as input so I used 'lapply'  and 'lm' functions to 'US.data.daily' data in this way:

`mod<-lapply(US.data.daily,function(x)  lm(spread~volatility,data=as.data.frame(x),na.action=na.exclude))`

Now I would like to apply msmFit to each element of the 'mod' list, here the code:

`mod_mswm<-lapply(mod,function(x) msmFit(mod,k=2,p=0,sw=c(T,T,T),control=list(parallel=F)))`

It returns this error message:

`Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  : 
  unable to find an inherited method for function ‘msmFit’ for signature ‘"list", "numeric", "logical", "numeric", "missing", "missing"’`

I am supposing that the problem is that the list 'mod' is boult with 'list' class elements and not with elements with 'lm' class. This is because `class(mod[1])` gives me 'list'

I tried with: `class(mod[1]) <-c("lm")` but it doesn't work.

I have fund suggestions here[make a list of lm objects, retain their class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10425173/make-a-list-of-lm-objects-retain-their-class), but I can't write it for 91 times. I am looking for a quicklier way

Anyone knows if the problem is due to this reason? How could I solve the problem or how to convert element within the list to 'lm' class? I don't have to change the class of the entire list, but the class of each element.

ok, as you asked here there is the output given by `dput` function.
after: `mod_mswm <- lapply(mod, function(x) try(msmFit(x, k=2,p=0,sw=c(T,T,T),control=list(parallel=F))))`

and: `dput(mod_mswm_1, file = "mod_mswm_1")` the output is:

`list(structure("Error in if ((max(abs(object[\"Fit\"][\"logLikel\"] - oldll))/(0.1 + max(abs(object[\"Fit\"][\"logLikel\"]))) <  : \n  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed\n", class = "try-error", condition = structure(list(
    message = "missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed", call = if ((max(abs(object["Fit"]["logLikel"] - 
        oldll))/(0.1 + max(abs(object["Fit"]["logLikel"]))) < 
        control$tol) & (max(abs(object["Coef"] - oldcoef))/(0.1 + 
        max(abs(object["Coef"]))) < control$tol)) break), .Names = c("message", 
"call"), class = c("simpleError", "error", "condition"))), <S4 object of class structure("MSM.lm", package = "MSwM")>, 
    <S4 object of class structure("MSM.lm", package = "MSwM")>, 
    structure("Error in if ((max(abs(object[\"Fit\"][\"logLikel\"] - oldll))/(0.1 + max(abs(object[\"Fit\"][\"logLikel\"]))) <  : \n  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed\n", class = "try-error", condition = structure(list(
        message = "missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed", call = if ((max(abs(object["Fit"]["logLikel"] - 
            oldll))/(0.1 + max(abs(object["Fit"]["logLikel"]))) < 
            control$tol) & (max(abs(object["Coef"] - oldcoef))/(0.1 + 
            max(abs(object["Coef"]))) < control$tol)) break), .Names = c("message", 
    "call"), class = c("simpleError", "error", "condition"))), 
    structure("Error in if ((max(abs(object[\"Fit\"][\"logLikel\"] - oldll))/(0.1 + max(abs(object[\"Fit\"][\"logLikel\"]))) <  : \n  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed\n", class = "try-error", condition = structure(list(
        message = "missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed", call = if ((max(abs(object["Fit"]["logLikel"] - 
            oldll))/(0.1 + max(abs(object["Fit"]["logLikel"]))) < 
            control$tol) & (max(abs(object["Coef"] - oldcoef))/(0.1 + 
            max(abs(object["Coef"]))) < control$tol)) break), .Names = c("message", 
    "call"), class = c("simpleError", "error", "condition"))), 
    <S4 object of class structure("MSM.lm", package = "MSwM")>, 
    <S4 object of class structure("MSM.lm", package = "MSwM")>, 
    <S4 object of class structure("MSM.lm", package = "MSwM")>, 
    <S4 object of class structure("MSM.lm", package = "MSwM")>, 
    <S4 object of class structure("MSM.lm", package = "MSwM")>, 
    structure("Error in if ((max(abs(object[\"Fit\"][\"logLikel\"] - oldll))/(0.1 + max(abs(object[\"Fit\"][\"logLikel\"]))) <  : \n  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed\n", class = "try-error", condition = structure(list(
        message = "missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed", call = if ((max(abs(object["Fit"]["logLikel"] - 
            oldll))/(0.1 + max(abs(object["Fit"]["logLikel"]))) < 
            control$tol) & (max(abs(object["Coef"] - oldcoef))/(0.1 + 
            max(abs(object["Coef"]))) < control$tol)) break), .Names = c("message", 
    "call"), class = c("simpleError", "error", "condition"))), 
    structure("Error in if ((max(abs(object[\"Fit\"][\"logLikel\"] - oldll))/(0.1 + max(abs(object[\"Fit\"][\"logLikel\"]))) <  : \n  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed\n", class = "try-error", condition = structure(list(
        message = "missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed", call = if ((max(abs(object["Fit"]["logLikel"] - 
            oldll))/(0.1 + max(abs(object["Fit"]["logLikel"]))) < 
            control$tol) & (max(abs(object["Coef"] - oldcoef))/(0.1 + 
            max(abs(object["Coef"]))) < control$tol)) break), .Names = c("message", 
    "call"), class = c("simpleError", "error", "condition"))), 
    <S4 object of class structure("MSM.lm", package = "MSwM")>, 
    structure("Error in solve.default(res$Hessian) : \n  system is computationally singular: reciprocal condition number = 2.66759e-17\n", class = "try-error", condition = structure(list(
        message = "system is computationally singular: reciprocal condition number = 2.66759e-17", 
        call = solve.default(res$Hessian)), .Names = c("message", 
    "call"), class = c("simpleError", "error", "condition"))), 
    <S4 object of class structure("MSM.lm", package = "MSwM")>)`

Answer (score 0):

Not tested, something like this:

```
mod_mswm <-
  lapply(split(US.data2,"days"),
         function(x)
           msmFit(mod,
                  lm(spread~volatility,data=as.data.frame(x),na.action=na.exclude),
                  k=2,p=0,sw=c(T,T,T),control=list(parallel=F)))
```

Comment: the same error continues, according to it nothing have been changed

Answer (score 0):

You are using `mod` instead of `x` in your `function(x)`. This is of `class` `list` instead of `lm`, that's what the error message is telling you.

```
mod_mswm<-lapply(mod,function(x) msmFit(x, k=2,p=0,sw=c(T,T,T),control=list(parallel=F)))
```

EDIT: Your new error seems to be when calling the `msmFit` function. You could run the code with a `try`.

```
mod_mswm <- lapply(mod, function(x) 
  try(msmFit(x, k=2,p=0,sw=c(T,T,T),control=list(parallel=F))))
```

Then you can look at

```
lst[sapply(mod_mswm, class)=="try-error"]
mod[sapply(mod_mswm, class)=="try-error"]
```

Perhaps this makes it clear, why you get the error. Otherwise you should `dput` the output and post it as part of your question.

Comment: this code starts to work but after few seconds it gives me this error, now I don't have any idea what does it mean:       Error in if ((max(abs(object["Fit"]["logLikel"] - oldll))/(0.1 + max(abs(object["Fit"]["logLikel"]))) <  : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed

Comment: I have tried 
`mod_mswm <- lapply(mod, function(x) try(msmFit(x,k=2,p=0,sw=c(T,T,T),control=list(parallel=F))))`
and it gived me the same error as before plus this one: 
`Error in solve.default(res$Hessian) : 
Lapack routine dgesv: system is exactly singular: U[3,3] = 0`
then I ran:
`list[sapply(mod_mswm, class)=="try-error"]`
the result is:
`Error in list[sapply(mod_mswm, class) == "try-error"] : 
  object of type 'builtin' is not subsettable`while running:`mod[sapply(mod_mswm, class)=="try-error"]` it shows:
`Call: lm(..)
Coefficients:
(Intercept)   volatility  
     0.8411           NA`

Comment: Although the error is still displayed, it should still creates the object `mod_mswm` and you can run the subsequent codes that I put in the answer. Give us the data of the `list` element, where the error occurs. Otherwise it is impossible to diagnose the problem.

Comment: did you ask about the `mod` or mod_mswm` file? the second is posted into the question, the first one seems too big to be posted here.